# What's the meaning of "might" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She looks like she might make a competent nurse.

What's the meaning of "might" here? Does it have a certain meaning or it just plays a grammatical role?

The fuller text is here:

> The writer herself is rather austere looking. Dark hair pulled back
>   from her face in a tight ponytail. Strong bones. No-nonsense skirt and
>   sweater, equally no-nonsense eyeglasses. She looks like she **might** make
>   a competent nurse. The only flourish is a pretty scarf around her
>   neck. Not unattractive but getting on. Maybe pushing forty.

Comment: This is definition 1 in any dictionary lookup.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't understand the meaning of the sentence "She looks like she might make(may) a competent nurse" could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

"Might make a competent nurse" means that the narrator believes that she might be able to competently fulfill the duties associated with the role of a nurse, but they're not completely sure. In general, "might make for an [adjective] [position]" is an idiom that means that the speaker believes that the person in question will fulfill the role of [position] in an [adjective] fashion, e.g. "might make for a below-par programmer" means that the speaker believes that the person in question will program in a below-par fashion.

Comment: And could you explain please, what the relathionship between this and the previous sentences is?

Comment: The narrator is judging the person's competency based upon their appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally **might** is used in situations where there is possibility in the absence of impediments.  There is no reason to think it couldn't be true or couldn't happen.

> The hammer might be out in the tool shed. Or it might be on the workbench in the basement.

I find the phrase **might make** in the passage you quoted a tad strange. I'd expect  **might be**, or perhaps **would make**, but even that is odd. The look referred to is the look of a stereotypical no-nonsense nurse, not the look of someone who could *become* a no-nonsense nurse.

The phrase "might make" refers to the potential to be something:

> He's got great speed and technical skills. He might make a fine striker.

Comment: Your answer is reasonable. But could you please tell me what the relationship between this sentence(She looks like she might ...) and the previous sentences is?

Comment: The answer to your question is found in my answer. "The look referred to is the look of a stereotypical no-nonsense nurse". The emphasis is on *competence*, not "bedside manner".

Comment: And **no-nonsense eyeglasses**? What does it mean? Is it in use?

Comment: **no-nonsense** can be paraphrased as "emphasis on functionality not style". These glasses do not have "designer frames". They are "utilitarian".